# Proof: Line joining the image and the object is always perpendicular to the mirror

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I tried to find a proof, but couldn't find one. Anyone knows?

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is.

Comment: @noah If we take a mirror, and place an object in front of it, and join the image and the object, the line will be perpendicular to the mirror.

Comment: @noah apparently it is also true for spherical mirrors

Comment: From intuition, I would guess that it is due to angle of incidence = angle of reflection

Comment: @Jonas Hmmmmmm...(?)

Answer (score 1):

With a flat mirror, the virtual image is behind the mirror. If you consider any light ray from the object which reflects off of the mirror, the extension of that ray behind the mirror forms a triangle with the mirror and the normal which is identical with that formed by the ray before it hits the mirror.  Two or more such rays locate the image (on the normal).